# PHP inside HTML file - Simple Form and Validator

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts

I am working on this **school project** and I am having trouble getting my form to LOOK and FUNCTION properly.

[This is my School Project](http://glustik.com/)

**Issues/Question(s):**
1) Can I even Use this PHP "inside" an HTML document?
***([The Demo I am Trying to Follow](http://dreamweavertutorial.co.uk/contact.php))***

This is my FORM ENTRY *(IN AN HTML DOC)* :

```
<div id="formWrap">
        <div id="form">
            <form action="contact.php" method="post" id="comments_form">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="label">Your Name</div>
        <div class="input">
            <input type="text" id="fullname" class="detail" name="fullname" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['fullname'])? $_POST['fullname'] : ''; ?>" />

            <?php if(in_array('fullname', $validation)): ?><span class="error"><?php echo $error_messages['fullname']; ?></span><?php endif; ?>

        </div> <!-- end input class -->
        <div class="context">e.g. John Smith or Jane Doe</div><!-- end context class -->
     </div><!-- end row class -->

     <div class="row">
        <div class="label">Your Email Address</div>
        <div class="input">
            <input type="text" id="email" class="detail" name="email" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['email'])? $_POST['email'] : ''; ?>" />

            <?php if(in_array('email', $validation)): ?><span class="error"><?php echo $error_messages['email']; ?></span><?php endif; ?>

        </div> <!-- end input class -->
        <div class="context">We will not share your email address with anyone.</div><!-- end context class -->
     </div><!-- end row class -->

     <div class="row">
        <div class="label">Tell Us All About It!</div>
        <div class="input">
            <textarea id="comment" name="comment" class="mess">
                <?php echo isset($_POST['comment'])? $_POST['comment'] : ''; ?>
            </textarea>

            <?php if(in_array('comment', $validation)): ?><span class="error"><?php echo $error_messages['comment']; ?></span><?php endif; ?>

        </div> <!-- end input class -->
     </div><!-- end row class -->

     <div class="submit">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Send Message" />
        </form>
        <?php else: ?>
            <p>Thank you for your Message!</p>
        <?php endif; ?>

     </div><!-- end submit class -->
     </div><!-- end form -->

        <?php if($form_complete === FALSE): ?>

     </div><!-- end form wrap -->
```

Comment: Is PHP installed on the server that's hosting that website? If not, the PHP won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP blocks (`<?php ?>`) must be processed by the PHP parser/interpreter.  This means that the engine needs to know which files to read and which ones to ignore.  If this file is named `index.html` the PHP interpreter will ignore it (by default, you can change this, but it's not really an common or recommended thing to do).

You can correctly put HTML inside of a PHP file (but outside of the `<?php ?>` blocks) but you cannot successfully put PHP inside of an HTML file.

If your file is named `index.html` try renaming it `index.php` and see if your code works.

Comment: OK thats good to know. I will try and rework this and get back with you. Thanks. Also, just to clarify - html5 works just fine in a index.php scenario?

Comment: If the HTML is included outside of a PHP block, then yes, the interpreter will run the PHP and output the HTML without affecting it.

Comment: Yes change index.html to index.php

Answer (score 1):

You can change your server configuration to parse `HTML` files as `PHP` if you really want to keep `html` extension.

For example in an `Apache` server with `PHP` installed, you can create a `.htaccess` file in your website directory and use `AddType` directive:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

or alternatively you can edit `php.ini` file.

Answer (score 0):

You either don't have PHP installed or your web server is not configured to pass `.html` files to PHP. Judging by the fact that [this page](http://glustik.com/index.php) exists, PHP is installed, you probably just need to rename your file from `index.html` to `index.php`, or reconfigure Apache / your web server.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi - ummmm, it did when I posted this answer, "buddy".